# Escaped string insert into DIV with jQuery as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following escaped string

```
var myHtml = "&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://test.com&quot;&gt;Test: this is my test string.&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
```

I am trying to insert the HTML into a div called `#test`

```
$('#test').html(myHtml);
```

However, the tags are visible and the actual DOM objects are not inserted. It just appears as a string:

```
<P><A HREF="https://test.com">Test: this is my test string.</A></P>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanilla JavaScript will do just fine.
Harvesting the power of good old DHTML for doing the heavy lifting..., and there you go. Done!
Without even touching the original string.

```js
var html = "&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://test.com&quot;&gt;Test: this is my test string.&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"

test.innerHTML = html;
test.innerHTML = test.innerText;
```

```html
<div id=test></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, the tags are visible and the actual DOM objects are not
> inserted. It just appears as a string

Indeed it is a string. In order to convert it to html you need to change all **&lt ;** and **&gt ;** in the corresponding **<** and  **>** using string [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Or you can write twice in the div:

```
$('#test').html(myHtml);
$('#test').html($('#test').text());  // set the text now with < and > correctly converted
```

The snipet:

```js
var myHtml = "&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://test.com&quot;&gt;Test: this is my test string.&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"

$('#test').html(myHtml.replace(/&lt;|&gt;/g, e => e == '&lt;' ? '<' : '>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#text").text(myHtml);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var converted= $('<textarea />').html(myHtml).text();
$('#test').html(converted);
```

When we use the HTML function of the textarea element, myHTML content is rendered in textarea. All the Html tag is showed in textbox. We can get all the HTML code from the text.
And then we can add it in any element.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.